# SAP ui5 table odata

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an ODATA source coming from SAP BPMN and it gives an response like the following when I have the expand data. I have problems with getting the data from the odata and show it in  my table. The table does not show any lines.

The OData can be seen below. I bind the data with the following way.

```js
odataModel.read("/SAPBPMInputData('" + taskId + "')", null, ["$expand=startTypeINPUT/start/DO_SES/Lines"], false, function(data, response){
    // in case the response is incomplete, complement the model with dummy data objects
    ApproveSESComponent.DO_SES.util.ModelBuilder.completeJSONModelAccordingSchema(data, odataModel.getServiceMetadata().dataServices.schema[0], "SAPBPMInputData");
    var oODataJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);
    oODataJSONModel.setDefaultBindingMode("TwoWay");
    oView.setModel(oODataJSONModel);
    // eases the access for the controller
    oView.setModel(odataModel, "odataModel");
    oTable.setModel(oModel).bindRows("/Lines");
   }, function(oEvent){
    ApproveSESComponent.DO_SES.util.ErrorHandler.handleRequestFailedError(oEvent.response, resourceBundle);
   });
```

In my table view looks like the following.

```html
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"
 xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"  xmlns:t="sap.ui.table" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">

  <Table
   headerText="{i18n>LineItemTableHeader}"
   items="{path: 'odataModel>/Lines'}" >
   <columns>
    <Column>
     <header><Label text="Products" /></header>
    </Column>
    
   </columns>
   <ColumnListItem
    type="Navigation"
    press="handleLineItemPress" >
    <cells>
     <ObjectIdentifier
      title="{ID}" />
     
      
    </cells>
   </ColumnListItem>
   </Table>
 </core:FragmentDefinition>
```

OData:

```html
{  
   "d":{  
      "__metadata":{  
         "id":"/bpmodata/taskdata.svc/d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e/SAPBPMInputData('d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e')",
         "uri":"/bpmodata/taskdata.svc/d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e/SAPBPMInputData('d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e')",
         "type":"BPMTaskData.SAPBPMInputData"
      },
      "EDM_Key":"d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e",
      "startTypeINPUT":{  
         "__metadata":{  
            "id":"/bpmodata/taskdata.svc/d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e/startTypeINPUT('d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1')",
            "uri":"/bpmodata/taskdata.svc/d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e/startTypeINPUT('d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1')",
            "type":"BPMTaskData.startTypeINPUT"
         },
         "EDM_Key":"d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1",
         "start":{  
            "__metadata":{  
               "id":"/bpmodata/taskdata.svc/d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e/Form('d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1_1')",
               "uri":"/bpmodata/taskdata.svc/d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e/Form('d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1_1')",
               "type":"BPMTaskData.Form"
            },
            "EDM_Key":"d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1_1",
            "DO_SES":{  
               "__metadata":{  
                  "id":"/bpmodata/taskdata.svc/d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e/DO_SES('d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1_1_1')",
                  "uri":"/bpmodata/taskdata.svc/d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e/DO_SES('d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1_1_1')",
                  "type":"BPMTaskData.DO_SES"
               },
               "EDM_Key":"d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1_1_1",
               "CustomerID":"23523",
               "CustDate":"\/Date(1433116800000+0180)\/",
               "Total":"230.0",
               "SESID":"235",
               "Lines":{  
                  "results":[  
                     {  
                        "__metadata":{  
                           "id":"/bpmodata/taskdata.svc/d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e/LinesType('d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1_1_1_1_1')",
                           "uri":"/bpmodata/taskdata.svc/d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e/LinesType('d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1_1_1_1_1')",
                           "type":"BPMTaskData.LinesType"
                        },
                        "EDM_Key":"d06785d9085e11e5bd990000062c3c6e_I_1_1_1_1_1",
                        "ID":"1",
                        "Description":"43",
                        "UnitPrice":"50.0",
                        "Quantity":"40.0",
                        "LineTotal":"20.0"
                     },
...... MORE LINEs
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had missed the results part of the response. So my table now is.

```
<Table
     id="idLineTable"
        items="{path:'Lines/results'}"
  >
```